# Setting zoom level for labels of highway in JOSM?

Tags: shapefile, openstreetmap, style, josm

I'm new in using JOSM and OpenStreetMap data . I import a shapefile of highways in JOSM and use it for styling the highways.Some highways are trunk ( in open street map standard ) and some of are primary . When i style highways, the name of highways  display in zoom level of  17 on map . I want to labeling the highways in zoom level of 12 .

How can i change the zoom level for name of the highways?

Comment: Did you try to derive an own JOSM map style? http://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles

Comment: @Mapper no i didn't . I'l try it. Thanks

Comment: @Mapper I try it . it's working well . Thanks a lot . please answer my quetion for accepting your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOSM has the feature to define custom map styles: http://josm.openstreetmap.de/wiki/Styles